# GitBash: Avoid losing work I didnt commit from yesterday

Tags: git, git-bash

I did some work on Monday (for example) and didnt commit before logging out for the day.  Now I boot my computer up on Tuesday morning and want to do the commit using Git Bash.

How do I get to my develop branch directly and avoid doing a checkout of master and overwrite my changes?  Is there a way to have master and 'develop' branch be in different directories?

I feel like this happened once where I went back into bash and the default branch was master and I was worried about doing a checkout to get to my develop branch to do the commits.

I am fairly new to Git and want to make sure I am following best practices and understanding the fundamentals of Git correctly

Comment: You should consider reading the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) to understand the basics (I have no idea why you need to checkout anything or why not committing yesterday even matters).

Comment: I have but can't find a solution to getting around this problem.  Will GitBash always come up with the branch I left off from yesterday?

Comment: Yes, unless you checkout a different branch. If you *do* need to work on a different branch without losing any changes, either commit those changes or do a `git stash` to stash those changes for later before doing the branch checkout.

Comment: If you were working on your develop (ie. had your develop branch checked out) branch last thing yesterday, nothing will have changed today. Your HEAD pointer should still be pointing to your develop branch, and your worktree should still contain any uncommitted changes you made yesterday. Git will not automatically checkout the master branch, just because the remote master branch changed.

Comment: If you want to have a look at the master branch, just commit your current changes to your local develop branch, and then checkout master. When you are done looking at the master branch, you can checkout your develop branch and continue working where you left off.

Comment: [This](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) is an easy to understand guide to Git basics.